# Выделения пункта меню навигации

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >About</a></li>
</ul>

a { 
    background-color: blue;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
.selected {
    background-color: red;
    color: fff;
}
```

Как реализовать выделения пункта меню навигации, когда открыта данная станица из меню? Т.е. Открыта страница HOME и пункт меню подключает класс SELECTED. И как это выделения называется?

Comment: поищете в сторону `hashchange`, у вас появится 3 варианта:

- написать отлов этого события самостоятельно
- воспользоваться одним из многих плагинов для jQuery
- использовать специализированную [библиотеку](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Routing) для роутинга

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сайт статический, правильно я понимаю? Если так, то (1) сделать абсолютные ссылки в меню, (2) в jQuery:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
  return this.href === document.location.href;
}).parent().addClass("selected");
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, то что я и думал, сравнение ссылок!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeharmony.ru/materials/73 посмотри может поможет...если я все правильно понял.

Comment: Ты правильно понял, но мне нужно это сделать без PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так, и все отлично работает!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
    $('ul li a').each(function() {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $("li.current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        }
    }); 
});
```